# Problem with smbclient -L command - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, samba

I'm trying install an AD DC with Ubuntu 14.04 on my Raspberry Pi 2 following  [this guide](https://jimshaver.net/2014/07/13/setting-up-an-active-directory-domain-controller-using-samba-4-on-ubuntu-14-04/).

Currently on the last step of the guide when i type in the command:

```
smbclient -L dc1.weemaniac.net -U%
```

i get this error message

```
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
```

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Update: tried the command given to me in comments, now it allows me to put in my password but after i do this i still get the same error:

```
smbclient -L dc1.weemaniac.net -U administrator 
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_OJBECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
```

Update 2: finally found a solution to my problem. Only thing i had to do was install winbind and it started working right away.

Answer (score 0):

After your `-U` you need to put in the username you want to log in with.

So the command would be:

```
smbclient -L dc1.weemaniac.net -U administrator
```

Comment: Don't ask for accepts in the answer just ask in a comment, it keeps you answer tidy :)

Comment: From @danturnip "Please accept this answer if it was correct and the other question I answered before."

Comment: Thanks it just becomes tedious writing out the answers and then it not being accepted (assuming it's correct etc), I'll make sure to stick to your advice, thanks :)

Comment: It happens, that's one of the issues we all face round here, users just not returning to answer, right or not.

Comment: This command worked but when i typed in the password i created with Samba provisioning i get the same error message.

Comment: I know, oh well I guess it's all part of the deal :)

Comment: Try adding 'WEEMANIAC.NET\administrator' including the quotes after the -U, i can't edit my answer right now

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I've got the commands mixed up answering on my Mobile can't check what I'm saying, will edit answer shortly. Please comment if you fix before then.

Comment: @Danturnip Probably best not to answer on mobile, if you still want to makes some rep on a phone you can edit posts with bad grammar and spelling, each accepted one gets you 2 rep and really helps out :)